# How to remove space from breadcrumb in angular 2

Tags: angular

I am trying to remove space `%20` from breadcrumb.
`Microsoft%20D365` is an dynamic value in breadcrumb.

Example: Home > Market place > `Microsoft%20D365` > products

*which needs to read as :*
I need breadcrub like

Home > Market place > Microsoft D365 > products

I have tried code is 
breadcrumbService.addFriendlyNameForRouteRegex('/app/new/[a-zA-Z]/products', 'Products');
Getting breadcrumb is Home > Market place > `Microsoft%20D365` > products and i need ends with show the string 'Products'.

Answer (score 1):

For each element in the breadcrubms you can use  `decodeURIComponent(element)`

i.e: `decodeURIComponent('Microsoft%20D365') = 'Microsoft D365'`

Read more about [decodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent)

Comment: Hi, is this my breadcrumb service breadcrumbService.addFriendlyNameForRouteRegex('/apps/new/[A-Za-z]/products', 'Products');
[A-Za-z] here the value has been changed the dynamically and the value Microsoft%20D365 is dispalyed here. 
In run time i can't to remove the space from breadcrumb.It will take default value %20 for space.

Comment: You can make that change in the component containing the breadcrumb!

Comment: I have removed space from breadcrumb, its return output like 
Home > Market place > Microsoft D365 > Microsoft D365 .
i have tried the following code is
this.breadcrumbService.addFriendlyNameForRouteRegex('/app/new/[a-zA-Z]$', decodeURIComponent(this.Name)).


I need show ends with 'Products' .
Home > Market place > Microsoft D365 > products

Comment: Can you edit your question and show all the code relevant to the issue? My answer fixes the issue you mentioned in the question originally. But if there are other aspects to the issue, you need to put them in the question.